# AS3/Arrays: impossible duplication after "splice"

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, runtime-error, splice

I have a function that gets questions from an array called quizQuestions, displays the choosed question, splice it from the array and pushes the question and correct answer to a new array to be used later in the results screen:

```
// The questions are stored in an array called "quizQuestions"
function makeQuestion()
    var randNum:Number = Math.round(1 + (quizQuestions.length - 1) * Math.random());
    mc_quiz.question.text = quizQuestions[randNum][0];
    answer = quizQuestions[randNum][1];
    quizQuestions.splice(randNum,1);    
    printQuestions.push(new Array(mc_quiz.question.text, answer));
}
```

It runs fine but time to time, a question is asked twice. You can continue with the test but the result doesn't show the info. In fact, it only shows the results for the questions answered before the duplication. I have checked visually and with a "duplicated elements finder" and there are no duplicated questions in the array.

Could the splice non being executed time to time? Can you see any "bug" in the function?  Could it happen due to hardwer issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One bug I see is in the expression for calculating `randNum`. If you analyze it, you will notice that `1` ≤ `randNum` ≤ `quizQuestions.length`. If this is the actual range of indices of your array then it's not a bug. One thing to keep in mind though is that using `Math.round()` on `Math.random()` generates random numbers with non-uniform probability distribution. I explained the reason in this post: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=267201#post1104626

Comment: Thanks Omer. There are 60 questions and must be generated 10 random question from that list. If I undertand correctly the initial range is 0 to 59. Isn't it? Now, my random creator is generating results over a minimum lenght of 2 (remember the splice). I did a test with a loop (i<=60) and I did get the same array lenght when the lenght was 6. The last results were: 6 of 6 - 3 of 6 - 3 of 5 - 1 of 4 - 2 of 3 - 2 of 2. That mistake is due to the 1 ≤ quizQuestions.length?

Comment: var randNum:Number = int(Math.random()*quizQuestions.length) works like a charm. Thanks a lot for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your random number generation is not only mathematically wrong (i.e. it won't generate truly random items), it will also from time to time generate a number that is beyond the array's bounds. To explain this: `1+(array.length-1) * Math.random()` will generate any number greater or equal to 1 (this will also result in the first item of the array never to be returned, because arrays are 0-based), up to a fraction less than the actual length of the array. If you `Math.round()` the highest possible result, it will round up to the next highest integer, which is the full length again - and if you access `array[array.length]`, an error is thrown, which is probably responsible for the weird behavior you are seeing.

Here's a possible solution:

`Math.round()` creates random number bias, anyway (see [@OmerHassans link](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=267201#post1104626)), so you're better off using `int()` or `Math.floor()`. Also, [`Math.random()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#random%28%29) is defined as `0 <= n < 1`, so it will never return 1. Therefore, you can simplify your random index generator to `int(Math.random()*array.length)` => any integer smaller than the length of the array.
[`splice()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29), then, returns an array of the items that were removed, so you can pass its first item, instead of creating a new array.

```
function getRandomItem( arr:Array ):* {
    var rand:int = Math.random()*arr.length;
    return arr.splice( rand, 1 )[0];
}

function makeQuestion():void {
    var q:Array = getRandomItem( quizQuestions );
    mc_quiz.question.text = q[0];
    answer=q[1];
    printQuestions[printQuestions.length] = q;
}
```

FYI: It won't matter much in this context, but you get much faster performance by replacing `array.push(item)` with `array[array.length]=item;`.

Comment: Many thanks weltraumpirat. I did change the random creation to var randNum:Number = int(Math.random()*quizQuestions.length). I'll test the rest of your solution later. About the optimization, I love that kind of tip, indeed. Cheers.

Comment: I did test array[array.length]=item. Many thanks for that tip. What I don't understand is how to use the splice later. After the test, the app goes to a frame where I fill two pages, one with the info of the guy (they fill a form befor the test) and another with the questions, the guy choice for each one and the correct answer. I get that info from the array that y populate with the splice. How do I do the same with your splice method?

Comment: It's all in there, @Sergio - my `makeQuestion()` method should do exactly what your own version was supposed to do, except that it uses the `getRandomItem()` function to pick a question.

Comment: Notice that I push the question+answer array (`q`) to the `printQuestions` array at the end, just the same way that you did. I just don't create a new array out of question and answer, because it is not necessary - the array is already there.

Comment: Sorry, I was sleepy before. What I must call is makeQuestion(), and it will run getRandomItem() to get each question. Nice. Many thaks.